# How to keep custom html specified in gmail signature?

Tags: html, gmail, signature

This is the html code I used to create a gmail signature [(pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/0guwW1MZ).

```
<html>
<head><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
 <style>
        body
            {
                font-family: Quicksand;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
    </style>
<body link="42B2EB"!important>
<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/55436a5ce4b01cc1ee9e5bf4/t/57b43defb3db2b80ee097f26/1485346985445/?format=1500w" style="width:130px;height:25px;"><br>
<br><b><font style="font-family: Quicksand;"color="#42B2EB"!important; text-decoration:none !important;>Daria Kiseljak</font></b>
<br><b><font style="font-family: Quicksand;"color="#42B2EB"!important; text-decoration:none !important;>Mac Digital</font></b>
<br><b><font style="font-family: Quicksand;"color="#42B2EB"!important; text-decoration:none !important;>M:</b> 085-1234567</font>
<br><b><font style="font-family: Quicksand;"color="#42B2EB"!important; text-decoration:none !important;>E:</b></font>&ensp;<a style="font-family: Quicksand;" href="mailto:daria@example.ie">daria@example.ie</a>

<br><b><font style="font-family: Quicksand;"color="#42B2EB"!important; text-decoration:none !important;>W:</b> <a style="font-family: Quicksand;" href="http://www.example.ie/html/">www.example.ie</a>
<br><br>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com">
 <img src="https://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/wp-content/themes/emailsignatures/images/linkedin-35x35.gif" style="width:18px;height:18px;"></a>
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
 <img src="https://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/wp-content/themes/emailsignatures/images/facebook-35x35.gif" style="width:18px;height:18px;"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com">
 <img src="https://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/wp-content/themes/emailsignatures/images/twitter-35x35.gif" style="width:18px;height:18px;"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

It's working as an html document, but when pasted to gmail signature box, link colours and font change to Gmail's default font.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.